# Set class member value by its name

Tags: c++, qt, setvalue, class-members

I've a class, derived of `QObject` and it has some members.
I load a configuration file with `param value` syntax. Each `param` is a member of the class and I want to set it's value to `value`.

How is it possible, if it actually is? Thanks much!

PS I could have made an associative array but it's not the way I prefer.

Comment: You need to make the members into Qt properties.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong but aren't field names erased at compile time, making this sort of reflection impossible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two ways of doing this:

1. Declare your members as properties by using the `Q_PROPERTY` macro.  Then you can set it by name using `QObject::setProperty(..)`.
2. Declare a setter method with the property name (plus a 'set' prepended for example) and the `Q_INVOKABLE` macro (or just make it a `slot`), then use `QMetaObject::invokeMethod(..)` to call it by name.

Comment: I downvoted it becasue, TS clearly said he didn't want to use associative array and you suggesting to use it indirectly

Comment: @cmannett85 Thanks much, I just wonder, how do I pass a `QString` to `setProperty()`? Do I use `qPrintable()`?

Comment: @aleguna But the OP is already using the `Qt` library which is packed full of them.  As I understood it, the OP simply did not want to write his/her own.

Comment: @cmannett85 `the OP simply did not want to write his/her own` that is! And the final question. When I want to use this property as a string I just use `property("foo").toString()`, right?

Comment: I don't know how you come to that conclusion. He never said anything about writing his own

Comment: @Kolyunya If your "foo" property is a `QString` then yes, that looks right.

Comment: You don't have to put Q_INVOKABLE to property setters. If you use Q_PROPERTY(QString myProp READ getMyProp WRITE setMyProp) Qt moc will do whole work, and setProp("myProp", "myPropValue") will work

Comment: @KamilKlimek I've given two examples, the number '2' point does not use the property system.  But you are right.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible in c++. The only way is an associative array

Comment: @cmannett85, which uses some sort of associative array internally.

Comment: Maybe it does, but my -1 is for your first sentence.

Comment: My first sentense is correct. There is no way to do it in c++ unless you use an associative array, either directly in indirectly.

Comment: C++ has numerous associative arrays as a part of it's standard library, not to mention the hundreds of third party equivalents. So it is possible in C++ - as your second sentence notes.

Comment: It doesn't matter how many implementations of associative arrays are there. TS wanted to set the variable by name witout using them, and it's NOT possible in C++, full stop.